# Proving $(b + c) \cos \frac{B + C}{2} = a \cos \frac{B - C}{2}$ for any $\triangle ABC$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I found this problem on *Mathematics, Textbook for Class XI by NCERT, ed. January 2021* that uses the sine and cosine formulas along with standard trigonometric identities for proving an identity.
By triangle ABC, the question assumes that the angles of the triangle are A, B and C, and the sides opposite the angles A, B and C, are *a*, *b* and *c* respectively.

> For any triangle $ABC$, prove that:
> $$(b + c) \cos \frac{B + C}{2} = a \cos \frac{B - C}{2}$$

I've tried to approach this problem by simplifying the
$$\cos \frac{B+C}{2}$$

part into
$$\sin\frac{A}{2}$$

and assuming that
$$\frac{a}{\sin A} = \frac{b}{\sin B} = \frac{c}{\sin C} = k$$

keeping in mind the sine law. However, I haven't been able to solve it yet.

A guidance would be helpful even if the question is not solved in its entirety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin(B)+\sin(C)=2\sin\left(\frac{B+C}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right)$$
Multiply $\cos\left(\frac{B+C}{2}\right)$ on both sides, and use double angle formula for sine

$$(\sin(B)+\sin(C))\cos\left(\frac{B+C}{2}\right)=\sin(B+C)\cos\left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right)$$

$\sin(B+C)=\sin(\pi-A)=\sin(A)$

$$(\sin(B)+\sin(C))\cos\left(\frac{B+C}{2}\right)=\sin(A)\cos\left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right)$$

Use sine law: $\sin(A)=\frac{a}k, \sin(B)=\frac{b}k, \sin(C)=\frac{c}k$

$$(b+c)\cos\left(\frac{B+C}{2}\right)=a\cos\left(\frac{B-C}{2}\right)$$

Comment: The solution's fine; I've got no problems, except how did you understand that you'd have to use sin B + sin C and also that you'd have to multiply cos ((B+C)/2) on both sides?

Answer (score 3):

For fun, here's a trigonographic proof (for $B>C$):

[image]

Comment: That's a unique way to prove it. Thanks. Could you possibly tell me what software you used to create the picture?

Comment: @archthegreat: *That's a unique way to prove it.* That's kinda what I *do*. ;) ... I use GeoGebra for my figures. (Specifically, an aging copy of GeoGebra Classic 5 on my Mac. I rather dislike the web-like interface of the current versions of the app.)

Comment: beatifulllllllllllllllll

Answer (score 2):

First you need to know [*The sum to product identities*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities):
$$\sin B+\sin C=2\sin(\frac{B+C}{2})\cos(\frac{B-C}{2}) $$
Then the problem is solved:
$$
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
    (b+c)\cos(\frac{B+C}{2})-a\cos(\frac{B-C}{2}) &= R[(\sin B+\sin C)\sin(\frac{A}{2})-\sin A\cos(\frac{B-C}{2})] \\
         &= R\sin(\frac{A}{2})[(\sin B+\sin C)-2\cos (\frac{A}{2})\cos(\frac{B-C}{2})] \\
         &= R\sin(\frac{A}{2})[(\sin B+\sin C)-2\sin (\frac{B+C}{2})\cos(\frac{B-C}{2})] \\
         &= 0\\
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :)